# Android: Alert Dialog

Tags: android

Help....I have a problem...Here is the cod...

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
switch (id) {
case IDD_COLOR:
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Pick a color");
    ListView listView = new ListView (this);
    builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_multichoice, mColors ));

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

          @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            switch (arg2) {
            case 0: 
                if (!((CheckedTextView)arg0.getChildAt(arg2)).isChecked()) 
                {
                    ((CheckedTextView)arg0.getChildAt(arg2)).setChecked(true);
                } else 

                    ((CheckedTextView)arg0.getChildAt(arg2)).setChecked(false);

            break;
            case 1: 
                if (!((CheckedTextView)arg0.getChildAt(arg2)).isChecked()) 
                {
                    ((CheckedTextView)arg0.getChildAt(arg2)).setChecked(true);
                } else 

                    ((CheckedTextView)arg0.getChildAt(arg2)).setChecked(false);

                break;
            case 2: 
                if (!((CheckedTextView)arg0.getChildAt(arg2)).isChecked()) 
                {
                    ((CheckedTextView)arg0.getChildAt(arg2)).setChecked(true);
                } else 

                    ((CheckedTextView)arg0.getChildAt(arg2)).setChecked(false);

                break;
            }

        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            }
    });

    builder.setView(listView);
    return builder.create();
default:
return null;
}
```

How to cancel what was clicked by pressing Cancel Button ? Because It all the time save what was clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jony,

Would this work in your case?

```
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            ((CheckedTextView)arg0.getChildAt(arg2)).setChecked(false)
            dialog.cancel();
        }
});
```

I haven't tested it, but it seems if you simply uncheck the box before calling `dialog.cancel();` it shouldn't come up checked.

Comment: ))) That is bad answer...what is arg0 in your method ? ))

Comment: ah, sorry.  you are right you wouldnt' be able to access the checkbox from that method.

have you tried just adding `dialog.cancel()` into the `setNegativeButton` action?

Comment: Yep....It's not working....I think i should use OnPrepareDialog ....But i dont know how...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901837/android-alert-dialog-cancel-button/4902885#4902885